# Webpack5 не могу отрисовать изображения из css

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss, webpack5

Я делаю сборку на  webpack для верстки с поддержкой  SCSS, Pug при необходимости. Из html я могу отрисовать изображения, а если я пытаюсь отрисовывать из CSS в background-image, то ничего не получается.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const FileManagerPlugin = require('filemanager-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ImageMinimizerPlugin = require('image-minimizer-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        assetModuleFilename: path.join('img', '[name][ext]'),
        },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.pug$/,
                loader: 'pug-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: path.join('fonts', '[name][ext]'),
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/i,
                loader: 'html-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'template.html'),
            // template: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'template.pug'),
            filename: 'index.html',
        }),
        new FileManagerPlugin({
            events: {
                onStart: {
                    delete: ['dist'],
                },
                onEnd: {
                    copy: [
                        {
                            source: path.join('src', 'static'),
                            destination: 'dist',
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { 
                    from: "src/css/*.css", 
                    to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'css', '[name][ext]') 
                },
                { 
                    from: "src/js",
                    to: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'js', '[name][ext]')
                },
                {
                    from: "src/img",
                    to:   path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'img', '[name][ext]')
                }
            ],
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        watchFiles: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        port: 9000,
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new ImageMinimizerPlugin({
                minimizer: {
                    implementation: ImageMinimizerPlugin.imageminMinify,
                    options: {
                        plugins: [
                            ['gifsicle', { interlaced: true }],
                            ['jpegtran', { progressive: true }],
                            ['optipng', { optimizationLevel: 5 }],
                            ['svgo', { name: 'preset-default' }],
                        ],
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
    },
};
```

И почему-то у меня в корневой папке  src/js/main.js попадает в папку  dist/img. Точнее он попадает как туда, куда ему нужно в dist/js, но еще и в dist/img и лежит с изображениями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

src/js/main.js попадает в папку dist/img - я не вижу main.js , возможно вы имели ввиду index.js ?  И возможно причина именно в этом filename: 'index.js',
assetModuleFilename: path.join('img', '[name][ext]'). Но я не уверен.
Насчет отрисовывать из CSS то в путях мы всегда поднимаемся на уровень вверх чтобы попасть в папку img через ../ в отличие путей в html ./

Comment: Нет,  index.js это корневой, с ним все в порядке. У меня есть еще папка js, img, fonts с ними всё в порядке. Но почему-то файл main.js при сборке дополнительно ещё попадет в папку img

Comment: Почему main.js попадает в папку img я разобрался. Причина в том, что я его не импортировал в корневой файл  index.js, а отдельно подключал внутри тега body в самом низу.  Главная проблем в том, что картинка из такого вида <img src='./img/avatar.png' alt=""> превращается в такой <img src='img\avatar.png' alt=""> Из  html изображение отрисовывается, а из  CSS  нет.  Интересно, что в конечном  css файле у меня адрес к изображению выглядит вот так url(\img\search.svg). А в консоли показывает http://127.0.0.1:5500/dist/imgsearch.svg 404 (Not Found). Т.е он склеивает img + имя файла изображения.

Comment: Разобрался заменил assetModuleFilename: path.join('img', '[name][ext]') на  assetModuleFilename: 'img/[name][ext]', и все заработало как надо. Но всё равно интересно почему файлы  js которые я подключаю напрямую в главный файл  html в конечной сборке попадают в папку img